# How to retrieve image from database?

Tags: android

I want to save and retrieve the image from local database. I insert image as blob in db but I am usable to retrieve image.

Please help me.

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?  Using LINQ to SQL, the following code creates an HttpHandler and grabs a BLOB from a database...

```
public class GetFile : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Document document = new GigzDataContext().Documents.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == new Guid(context.Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()));
        context.Response.ContentType = document.ContentType;
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(document.Blob.ToArray());
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/GetBlob.html) to have a concept on how to retrieve blob data from a database table as bytes, and after you have them in bytes, you should be able to save them into proper format to form your final image.